# How to denote 4:00 PM for the previous day

Tags: c#

I am setting up a TimeSpan and need to find a way to put 4:00 PM or 16:00 for the previous day. Anything helps!

Comment: That's not a TimeSpan though, that's a DateTime, surely?

Comment: Not sure what you're doing here, but does this help? `var ts = TimeSpan.FromHours(-8); 
var yesterdayAt4PM = DateTime.Today.Add(ts);`

Comment: This sounds like a case for a (second) DateTime, not a TimeSpan. Why do you think you need TimeSpan?

Comment: 4:00 PM on the previous date is a time, not a time span. What have you tried?

Comment: I need to use TimeSpan because I am using that value to populate a SQL Database with a Time data type

Comment: No you don't - TimeSpan is a time interval, it's not a point in time.

Comment: The SQL data type `TIME` doesn't have a concept of _yesterday_, and a `TimeSpan` object is a time interval, not a point in time (as @500-InternalServerError said). To use either to represent a DateTime you'll need some sort of base date time to offset from by the specified time / timespan

Comment: Can you look at this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#date-and-time and verify in your question what SQL type you are trying to populate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var dt = new DateTime(now.Year,now.Month,now.Day,16,0,0).AddDays(-1);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. I apologize for the incorrect terminology in the original question.

Comment: Why using DateTime.Now when you dont need the clock? Use DateTime.Today instead. Eg. var dt = DateTime.Today.AddHours(-8);

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is use the concepts of cycle array in order to handle situation where you are in limits of day.

For example, add 4 hours at 23h would carry to another day, as the same of reduce 4 hours at 1 am.

This example I made a code that reduces 4 hours from the current time.

```
function get_hour(){
                    var decreaseValue = 4;

                    //Creating the cicle hour array
                    var cicleHoursArray = [];
                    for(var i = 0; i < 24; i++)
                    {
                        cicleHoursArray[i] = i;
                    } 

                    var currentTime= Date.now();
                    var currentHour = new Date(currentTime).getHours();

                    var newIndex = currentHour - decreaseValue;
                    var resultTime;

                    //Time from yesterday
                    if(newIndex < 0)
                    {
                        newIndex = 24 - newIndex;
                        //If you want to reduce one day, that is the spot for it
                    }

                    resultTime = cicleHoursArray[newIndex];
                }
```